# Manually specify wpf application installation path

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

After publish my wpf application through visual studio 2013 for windows, install the same application into my system.

The application is installing to below path.

**C:\Users\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0--------**

We want to install the application into the below path.

**C:\Program Files--------**

We didn't find any solution by online search.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce Deployment does not allow you to do this, they always go to the AppData folder and will be cleared if the ClickOnce cache is.

You are able to set where they will appear in the start menu by setting the Assembly Information correctly in the Project Properties.

To be able to install to a custom location or to make changes to the machine while installing you need to use a more in depth installer, a free example is [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) but be warned it is very complex and requires a lot more work than ClickOnce does, you will get the idea once you star to look through the documentation